# AngularJS creating new $scope that subtracts two $scopes consumed from a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, scope

I am very very new to AngularJS and programming and I am sure this is a basic question but I am having a difficult time finding our resources in how to achieve subtracting two $scope values consumed from a JSON file ($scope.carrierDiff).  I would appreciate any help you can provide.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-controller="SiteCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="site in sites">
            <li>{{site.ID}}</li>
            <li>{{carrierDiff}}</li>
       </ul>
    </div></body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
        app.controller("SiteCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('JSON/getsamplesitesCopy.json').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {   
                $scope.sites = data;
            $scope.carrierDiff = $scope.sites.Carrier - $scope.sites.Carrier2;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// log error
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You wrote to $scope.sites but you're doing your calculation on $scope.data. Which is it? I think that's your problem.

Comment: Is Carrier an Integer or a String? Please provide the structure of getsamplesitesCopy.json or create a JSFiddle.net project so we can see a reproduction of your issue.

Comment: it should be to $scope.sites @dman2306.  I corrected that but I still don't get a result for {{carrierDiff}}, the error I receive is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Carrier' of undefined.

Comment: @BrianGerhards Carrier and Carrier2 are both integers

Comment: `Cannot read property 'Carrier' of undefined` is essentially saying that `$scope.sites === undefined`.  That would only happen if you have no data, or this code isn't the *actual* code in use.

Comment: also, this code probably won't work the way you expect, unless you want the same `carrierDiff` value printed for every `site.ID`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to calculate this separately

$scope.carrierDiff = $scope.sites.Carrier - $scope.sites.Carrier2;

You just have to do this...

```html
<body >
    <div ng-controller="SiteCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="site in sites">
            <li>{{site.ID}}</li>
            <li>{{site.Carrier - site.Carrier2}}</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Can't believe it was that simple.  I do have a follow up question that I will add shortly.

Answer (score 0):

With my limited knowledge of what is coming back from the file you are retrieving, it seems as though you are referencing the JSON data incorrectly. You need to reference $scope.sites OR data, not a hacked up version of both. If the structure of data looks like this:

```
data = {Carrier: 5, Carrier: 4}
```

Then you would reference Carrier like so:

```
data.Carrier1
```

So when you move data to $scope.sites, you are referencing the JSON in data and it would be referenced without the need to point out that it came from data

```
$scope.sites.Carrier1
```

So you code should look like so:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nnfewy?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-controller="SiteCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="site in sites">
            <li>{{site.ID}}</li>
            <li>{{carrierDiff}}</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
        app.controller("SiteCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('JSON/getsamplesitesCopy.json').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {   
                $scope.sites = data;
            $scope.carrierDiff = $scope.sites.Carrier - $scope.sites.Carrier2;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// log error
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Another item to remember, you should have you `<script>` in the head or in the body, not outside. See the modification in the code above.

Comment: Thank you Brian for your answer.  I realize you added the values for Carrier and Carrier2 but in your answer, would I always get the result of two? or would it be dynamic to the values of Carrier and Carrier2 from the JSON?

Comment: As per your question, you asked why the addition of the numbers was not working, not how to make these dynamic in the output. You can reference the numbers in the output how you have it set up by replacing `<li>{{carrierDiff}}</li>` with `<li>{{site.Carrier - site.Carrier2}}</li>`, that is if you have `Carrier` AND `Carrier2` in every object in the JSON structure.